# Adding a new content type programmatically in .install file or .module file?

Tags: 7, nodes

There are 2 different ways to create a new content type programmatically.

- First one, which I also use, is to create it in your custom module's `.install` file in [`hook_install()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_install/7) using [`node_type_save()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_type_save/7) and attaching the fields also in [`hook_install()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_install/7) with [`field_create_field()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.crud.inc/function/field_create_field/7) and [`field_create_instance()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.crud.inc/function/field_create_instance/7) .
- The second one, which in [Node Example](https://drupal.org/project/examples) module is used, is to create it in your custom module's `.module` file using [`hook_node_info()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_info/7) and creating and attaching the field instances in [`hook_node_type_insert()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_type_insert/7)

I am preferring the first method, since my feelings say that is better to maintain (i.e. adding/updating new fields via [`hook_update_N()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_update_N/7)) and it suits better in `.install` file. But, I keep myself asking why it is done other way in Node Example module.

Does anyone know the CONs and PROs of using both methods to create a new content type in code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some hooks, like [`hook_delete`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_delete/7) are only called on the module that defines the node's content type. If you save content type to a database using [`node_type_save()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_type_save/7), it might not be recognized as "defined by module" - it acts as content types created by user. Unless, of course, you will set `$info['module']` to point at your module - in that case created entries should work the same way.

Answer (score 4):

A third method, which is often easier to maintain, especially if your node type will change over time, is to use [Features](http://drupal.org/project/features) to export the node type, fields, and field instances. You can still add custom code to the exported Features module, and Features will preserve that custom code (and any additional files) in future exports.

I used to use the .install file method for a long time, but Features' stability and UI/drush integration is good enough now that it saves me a lot of time manually getting the field info and node type info.

If you make changes to the node type/fields/etc., and re-export the feature module, you can update the feature in the UI or using drush `feature-revert` or `features-revert-all`.

Answer (score -3):

There will be no issue with that...with update method you can create the new content types...

Comment: Do you really think this is an ANSWER to the question of the cons and pros the OP is asking?